# Is there a way to determine which angles, $3\theta$, are trisectable into $\theta$? Even when the angle $3\theta$ isn't constructible to begin with?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, geometric-construction

Is there a way to determine which angles, $3\theta$, are trisectable into $\theta$?  Even when the angle $3\theta$ isn't itself constructible to begin with?

Answer (score 5):

This is taken directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#Algebraic_characterization).

> An angle $\theta$ can be trisected iff $4t^3-3t-\cos\theta$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q(\cos\theta)$.

For example, $3\pi/7$ is trisectible because, letting $c=\cos3\pi/7$,
$$4t^3-3t-c=4(t+2c^2-1)(t^2+(1-2c^2)t+c/2-c^2)$$
Here $8c^3-4c^2-4c+1=0$.

Comment: Should the occurrences of $\alpha$ on the right side of the equation be $\cos\alpha$?

Comment: Seemed like more dissonance than to just change the $\alpha$ to $\theta$. :-P ¶ +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @BrianTung What can you expect, I was trying to not repeat variable names...

Comment: Isnt your last line, $4t^3-3t-c=4(t+2c^2-1)(t^2+(1-2c^2)t+c/2-c^2)$, an algebraic truth regardless of the value of $c$. What does it prove to me?

Comment: Quick response. I didnt work all of the algebra, just a couple of terms. I presumed it was generally true. In any case Im still not sure what Im supposed to get out of it. Checking that an algebraic expression is reducible in some extension seems like just as much work as the original problem. Am I wrong? How can I systematically approach this? If the angle itself is not expressible algebraically then how can I confirm the expression holds and isnt off by some amount?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Most good computer algebra systems will have a way to factor over custom fields. You first need to find the minimal polynomial of $c$. Then create the field $\mathbb Q(c)$ and check for reducibility over this field.

Comment: Id like to back up a bit.  Why do you write $4t^3-3t-c=4(t+2c^2-1)(t^2+(1-2c^2)t+c/2-c^2)$ at all if it isnt generally true?  Where did you even get that expression and why call it an equality if it isnt one?  And what CAS are you using because I cant seem to find one that will correctly check the reducibility of a polynomial over a field extension and will confirm your result.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I just wrote it as an example of a trisectible angle. I used [Singular](https://www.singular.uni-kl.de) to perform the factorisation.

Comment: Well thats very niche. Probably shouldnt say most CASs then. I tried Mathematica, Matlab packages, Maxima, and am working on seeing if Maple will work. Ive tried all the big name ones and so far no luck. Ive never heard of Singular. I get you were just using an example but Im trying to confirm your result and am not having any luck. To see how its done, Im walking through an example. Now you clearly wrote $4t^3-3t-c=4(t+2c^2-1)(t^2+(1-2c^2)t+c/2-c^2)$ with an equality sign, but if you distribute the right hand side you dont get an equality. Im wondering whats going on here.

Comment: Maybe Im grossly ignorant here or maybe there is a communication error.  The equality as it is written applies to all real numbers... yet it is false in general. Im not sure what sort of transformation you have in mind that would fix that. Or what subset of the reals makes it true. With all due respect you are talking about a hell of a lot of steps here that you simply havent shown nor gone through the trouble of previously describing.  Could you please show the solution method without the vagueness, please? Dont presume I know more than I do.

Comment: Im not an expert in field extensions or in minimal polynomials (maybe youd like to show that minimum polynomial and how its put to use? or how it magically makes an inequality into an equality?). All Im asking for here is a thorough and fleshed out answers with justified steps.  But if youre just snatching your answer up from the CAS (especially one that no other will confirm) then it begs the question of how well you understand this material yourself.  Im looking for a conceptual explanation of the steps, not just a brute force calculator answer.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I added the minimal polynomial. The rest is up to you.